# Finding menu item in Communities Navigation bar

Tags: soql, community, rest-api, community-builder

I'm using Community and I have added few objects in the navigation bar as you can see in the screen below and my question is how to get the list of navigation bar (Opportunity/Leads...) using APEX/SOQL/REST Api in Community?

[image]

Comment: Which template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Label, NavigationLinkSetId, Target FROM NavigationMenuItem
```

NavigationMenuItem: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_navigationmenuitem.htm

NavigationMenuItemLocalization: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_navigationmenuitemlocalization.htm